# Adding Jersey MOXy fails Jetty run

Tags: java, json, jar, gradle, jersey

I'm testing out REST using Jersey, Hibernate and embedded Jetty. Initially, I was able to start everything up using `./gradlew clean jar && java -jar build/libs/<project>.jar`. However, I wanted to support JSON and read from docs that MOXy is Jersey's default JSON provider. So I added the following in my `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.19'
```

After which, I tried to build the jar and start up jetty but I get the following issue:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:940)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Here's my `build.gradle` file if it helps.

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'

    // Jetty
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.1.v20150714'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.3.1.v20150714'

    // Jersey
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.19'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.19'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.19'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-processing:2.19'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.19'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-sse:2.19'

    // Hibernate
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final'
    compile 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.domain.scaffolding.Main'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a bit more into how gradle builds the fat jar, what solved the issue was to fix `jar` block:

```
jar {
    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.domain.scaffolding.Main'
    }
}
```